# Storyboard without using auto layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using storyboard without auto layout for implemented some interface like on pic 
[image] 
but in simulator it looks 
[image: http://cl.ly/image/0G3D0j0b1E3D] 
and buttons not working,but when I put a checkmark 
[image] 
[image: http://cl.ly/image/2C0u1l3V0S2r] 
everything is working.
**Any ideas?**

Comment: Have you implemented any code, which operates any of these views?

Comment: Nope, only ui on storyboard, one outlet for uilabel and ibactions for buttons that's all, controller implemented through some lines of code `PostingViewController *postingViewcontroller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Sparksfly" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PostingViewController"];`

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of Attributes Inspector pane for this View Controller, especially Extend Edges section?

Comment: Yes of course http://cl.ly/image/1L1H0m3N0h36

Comment: I believe that the overlayView could have blocking the the buttons when it has autolayout on. Can you hide the overlayView and try again on Autolayout and see if the buttons are working?

Comment: The problem is the buttons blocking when autolayout off and everything is ok when autolayout on